Is it incorrect to add the same JQuery Validate rule twice to a dynamic field and is it detrimental?
I have a large number of dynamic cloned fields on a form. The fields are cloned groups.
Every time I add a clone I use a wildcard selector to allocate the rules to all the fields in the DOM.
        $('[name^=myfieldname]').each(function() {
            $(this).rules('add',{
                    required: true,
                    duplicatefield: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Myfieldname is required",
                    duplicatefield: "Myfieldname can not be duplicated"
                }
            });
        });

The reason I do this is so that I can can a single function that I can call each time a clone is added or reindexed to ensure that all the fields in the DOM have the correct rules.
The result of this is that I will be allocating the rule multiple times to any pre-existing fields.
Is it incorrect to do this and does jQuery ignore the duplicated (added) rule or simply overwrite it?
